# Show 2 Divs withs same ID and Class onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

Is there a way to show 2 Divs with the same id and class onClick with Jquery, cant solve this. (Div1/Class targetDiv)

Html:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <a  class="showSingle" data-target="1">Option 1</a> //With this
    <a  class="showSingle" data-target="2">Option 2</a>
    <a  class="showSingle" data-target="3">Option 3</a>
    <a  class="showSingle" data-target="4">Option 4</a>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 1</div> //Show this
<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 1 Second</div> //And this
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 4</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.showSingle').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $('.targetDiv').hide();
    $('#div' + $(this).data('target')).show();
});
$('.showSingle').first().click();
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/5709/

Thank you so much for your Help!

Comment: Your two divs should not have the same ID. ID's must be unique to each element. Classes however can be shared among multiple elements.

Comment: You should never have 2 elements with the same id. Id's need to be unique. Add the same class to whatever elements you want to group together (e.g. class of 'div1' to multiple elements) and then show that class.

Comment: my bad.. works all fine now. id's are unique.. should have know that ! Thank you all!

Comment: So, there is no problem now?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have more than one occurrence of an ID on one page.

ID = Identifier

If you want to have the ability of "binding" the visibility of elements on you page, you could use data attributes with the same value.

For example:

```
<div class="links">
    <a href="#group-1">Group 1</a>
    <a href="#group-2">Group 2</a>
    <a href="#group-3">Group 3</a>
  </div>

  <div class="some-class" data-id="group-1"></div>
  <div class="some-class" data-id="group-1"></div>
  <div class="some-class" data-id="group-2"></div>
  <div class="some-class" data-id="group-3"></div>
  <div class="some-class" data-id="group-2"></div>
```

Then:

```
var $links = $( '.links' ).find( 'a' );

$links.on( 'click', function ( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();

  var group = $( this ).attr( 'href' ).replace( '#', '' );

  $( '.some-class' ).hide();
  $( '.some-class[data-id="' + group + '"]' ).show();
});
```